# how to create single page app in reactjs without using react router

Tags: reactjs

i am making an app similar to [Google Doodles](https://www.google.com/doodles) reactjs and i am stuck somewhere

My problem is on click of a button ie **[image: more about doodles]** in screenshot I want to display a new component on same page while all the other components should be overwritten by this component.

I am not using react router as there are not much links to navigate to.

Here is My Code

```
var CurrentDay = React.createClass({
    handleChange:function(){
        alert("in handlechange")
    },

     render: function() {
          //alert("in CurrentDay")
          var cardStyle = {
                 display: 'block',
                 width: '20vw',
                 transitionDuration: '0.3s',
                 height: '30vw'
             }
       return ( <div> 
       {
            this.props.holidays.map(function(holidays,i) {
            console.log("holdidays date: " + holidays.date);
            if(holidays.date!="July 31")
            {
                //alert(holidays.image);
                console.log(" IF --- this data : "+this);
                return      

                <div>els</div>;                   
             }
                else
                    {
                    //alert("in elseeee");
                    console.log(" this data : "+this);
                    return        <div>
                    <h2 style={{color:'green'}}>Todays event</h2>
                    <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>

                    <div style={{padding:'20px 35px 20px 35px'}}> 
                    <MuiThemeProvider>
                    <Card style={cardStyle}>
                      <CardHeader
                        title="URL Avatar"
                        subtitle="Subtitle"
                        avatar="https://placeimg.com/800/450/nature"
                      />
                      <CardMedia>
                      <GifPlayer gif="public/images/GuruRamDass.gif" still="public/images/GuruRamDass.jpg" />
                      </CardMedia>

                      <CardText>
                      <h4 style={{color:'blue'}}>{holidays.occasion}</h4>
                      </CardText>
                      <CardActions>
<FlatButton label="More About Doodle" onClick={this.handleChange}/>
                      </CardActions>
                    </Card>
                    </MuiThemeProvider>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>;
                    } 
          }, this)
        }
       </div> );
     }
    });
module.exports.CurrentDay = CurrentDay;
```

I want when i click **FlatButton** my app should **only** display a new component while overwriting all the other components that are being displayed on the app.Is that Possible to Achieve without react router?

Please guide

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by simply using local state in some wrapper - you either display the item list, or if there is an item selected, you display the item detail.

```
class Wrapper extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ selected: null });
  }

  setSelected = (item) => {
    this.setState({ selected: item });
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.selected) {
      return (
        <ItemDetail item={this.state.selected} />
      );
    }

    return (
      <ItemList onItemSelect={this.setSelected}>
        <Item title="Item 1" />
        <Item title="Item 2" />
        <Item title="Item 3" />
      </ItemList>
    )
  }
}
```

This will not persist through any navigator changes and things like back buttons etc. will obviously not work, you will have to use some sort of routing to achieve that.

Comment: but this will also display the other data that is already this page is displaying.How to hide that while navigating to next page?

Comment: @VikramSaini You need to do what I described on the top level, where you display the other data.